# Using distinct in LINQ where >1 column involved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of records, 3 of the properties of which are

```
VendorId
VendorName
VendorDesc
```

There could be multiple instances of the same vendor.

What I wish to do is retrieve a "distinct" list of "VendorNames" with the VenderDesc property as well.

Returning one property is fine ie

```
var myVendorNameList = myRecords.Select(r=>r.VendorName).Distinct();
```

However I wish to add the VendorDesc to this list after which I interate through to output(Razor View) the content using foreach ie

```
foreach (var item in myVendors)
{
 Name: @item.VendorName 
 Desc: @item.VendorDesc 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307)

Comment: Thanks for this, however an example would be useful.

Comment: `myRecords.DistinctBy(r=>r.VendorName);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to `GroupBy` the field you want and decide *which* of the duplicate records you want:

```
myRecords.GroupBy(r=>r.VendorName)
         .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Works great, same as answer below, award answer to first in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy`.This will also return `VendorId` property but I think that is not a problem.

```
myRecords.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName).Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, using the  [morelinq's](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307) DistinctBy (as LB mentioned) or creating your own one would be more readable

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                 Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(x => keys.Add(keySelector(x)));
}
```

You can now use it as

```
myVendorNameList  = myRecords.DistinctBy(r=>r.VendorName);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. A different approach.